What are the possible ways of communicating and interconnecting objects in Roblox Luau?
one way is obviously to write a monolithic source-only, single-script game (which leads to bad code organization and structure)
second is to use OOP-style classes (metatables) and a central hub which knows everything about them (which leads to unnecessary complex systems)
third and, it seems, the most recommended way is to use remote events everywhere (which potentially leads to unmaintainable spaghetti code pretty soon)
but are there any other ways of communicating, making calls, passing arguments and states between scripts in Roblox?
